# Date coming back in wrong format using JS remoting

Tags: apex, javascript, javascript-remoting

I return instances of an APEX Class in a JS remoting API.

```
public class OpportunityDetail {
     ...
     public Date closeDate;
     ...
```

The problem what is returned to my JavaScript client code is Date in the form:

```
1368057600000
```

When it should be:

```
2013-05-09
```

Any ideas how I could ensure that JS Remoting would return it in the format

```
2013-05-09
```

Answer (score 3):

You could initialize a new Date in Javascript from the long millisecond format that you are getting back.

```
var myDate = new Date(1368057600000);
myDate.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + myDate.getDate() + "-" + myDate.getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could format the milliseconds to the date on the client side?

```
var d = new Date(1368057600000);
var day = d.getDay();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();
if(day < 10)
    day = '0' + day;
if(month < 10)
    month = '0' + month;
var formattedDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
alert(formattedDate);
```